# Confusion about least upper bound property of reals constructed as Dedekind Cuts.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm currently reading through Pugh's Analysis, and just finished reading the proof of the Least Upper Bound property of the reals. The proof is pretty straight forward, there's just a little subtlety that I think I'm missing. Here's the proof.

Let $\mathcal{C}\subset \mathbb{R}$ with an upper bound, let's say $X|Y$. We define $C$ to be the set $\{a\in\mathbb{Q}: \text{for } A|B\in\mathcal{C}\text{, } a\in A\}$ and the set $D$ to be the remainder of $\mathbb{Q}$. Clearly $C|D$ is a cut, and since for all $A|B\in \mathcal{C}$ $A\subset C$, $C|D$ is an upper bound of $\mathcal{C}$. Let $C'|D'$ be any cut that bounds $\mathcal{C}$ above. Clearly, $C\subset C'$ and $C|D$ is the least upper bound.

I mostly understand the above proof. Here's what's confusing me. Doesn't $C$ being the union of all of the left halves of the cuts in $\mathcal{C}$ imply that the cut $C|D$ is in $\mathcal{C}$? Clearly this can't be true, because then the set of all numbers less than three would contain three for example. This is where I'm confused. Can someone explain like I'm six?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Doesn't $C$ being the union of all of the left halves of the cuts in $\mathcal{C}$ imply that the cut $C|D$ is in $\mathcal{C}$?"*

No, it doesn't. In general when you have a (countably) infinite amount of sets $H_0 \subseteq H_1 \subseteq ...$, then $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} H_n=H$ doesn't have to be equal to $H_n$ for any $n$. (for example $H_n := \{0,1,2,...,n\};$ then $H = \mathbb{N}$)

To take your example, the set of all numbers less than three doesn't contain the cut $C|D$ where $C=\{a \in \mathbb{Q}| a<3\}$ and $D = \mathbb{Q}\setminus C$ (since that corresponds to $3$); but $C$ is exactly what you get by taking the union of all the left halves of the cuts in this set.

Hope this answers anything. :)

Comment: Alright, I think I mostly get it. Can you explain what it is about infinity that makes this so? In my head, this still seems somewhat paradoxical. I guess my reasoning is that since every $H_n \subset H$ $H > H_n$ for all $H$. On the other hand though, since $H$ is the union of all $H_n$, there is no element in $H$ that does not appear in some $H_n$, which is what's bugging me still. Infinity makes my head hurt.

Comment: *"There's no element in $H$ that does not appear in some $H_n$"* - that's true, but the more important statement here is that "for every $n$ there's an element of $H$ that's not in $H_n$" (and so they can't be equal). This doesn't necessarily help though - infinity is a strange beast :)

Comment: It's confusing to me that both the above statements can be true. Do you know a resource where I can read more about this?

Comment: These statements (or a very similar form of them) can be simultaneously true even in finite cases: consider $A_1=\{1\}, A_2= \{2\}, A = A_1\cup A_2$; then every element of $A$ is in some $A_i$ and for every $i=1,2$ there's an element of $A$ that's not in $A_i$.


Your confusion might stem from a lack of familiarity with logical statements, quantifiers and such (correct me if I'm wrong though!). I can't think of any resource that deals specifically with that - you could try playing around with "for all" and "there exists" statements and their negations, for example.

Comment: I'm fine with statements and quantifiers. I think I'm being freaked out by the fact that left part of every successive cut in $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of the left part of the next cut, so I guess, to use your example, my intuition for cuts looks more like $A_1 = \{1\}$ and $A_2 = \{1, 2\}$ for which the above statements do not hold for $A$, $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: That's true. In this case the second statement can only be true when we take the union of an infinite amount of sets - otherwise our set will just be the largest of the sets we've started with; but an infinite family of sets doesn't have to have a largest element. My example was only trying to show that the two statements are unrelated. 

I suppose that phenomena like this that happens when one is considering infinity gets intuitive after some time. (or it may be that my knowledge is too limited to see how unintuitive they can get in fact)

Comment: Not at all, this was enlightening. I think I just need to ponder infinite sets for a bit.